# RStudio - Scrolling in output of str_view_all

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse, stringr

I recently started using the `stringr`-package in RStudio. I really like the `str_view_all` function. Currently I'm working with a large dataset of strings and like to look at the matches. `str_view_all` works alright, but sadly I'm not able to scroll through the output (on the right). When extending the viewport for the output more lines are shown.

Is there a way to scroll through this output (I can't further extend the viewport at some point)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to scroll through the output in RStudio's Viewer tab: https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/127

Try the "View in new window" shortcut on top of the Viewer, it allows you to see the full output in a web browser.